# Same Gnuplot linestyle as in graph in key/legend

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a legend/key, which shows the different symbols on the line. Currently my plots look like this:

[image: Current plot]

Unfortunately the symbols (triangle, rectangle and circle) are not shown in the key/legend. How is it possible to add them?

I use the following gnuplot script:

```
set title tit   font "palatino,20"
set xlabel xlbl font "palatino,20"
set ylabel ylbl font "palatino,20"
#set logscale x

set output graphfilename.".pdf"
set terminal pdf

set border linewidth 2
set style line 1  lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 5 # --- blue
set style line 2  lc rgb '#00ad60' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 # red     .
set style line 3  lc rgb '#ad0000' lt 1 lw 2 pt 9 # green     .

set tics scale 0.8

set key below 

plot file1 using ($1/1000):($2/1000000):($3/1000000):($4/1000000) notitle w yerrorbars ls 1, \
 '' using ($1/1000):($2/1000000) title "Hlog" w lines ls 1,\
file2 using ($1/1000):($2/1000000):($3/1000000):($4/1000000) notitle w yerrorbars ls 2, \
 '' using ($1/1000):($2/1000000) title "Iris" w lines ls 2,\
file3  using ($1/1000):($2/1000000):($3/1000000):($4/1000000) notitle w yerrorbars ls 3, \
 '' using ($1/1000):($2/1000000) title "Java" w lines ls 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can get both lines and points, if you plot with the `linespoints` plotting style:

```
sc(x) = x*1e-6
plot file1 using ($1/1000):(sc($2)):(sc($3)):(sc($4)) notitle w yerrorbars ls 1 ps 0.5, \
     '' using ($1/1000):(sc($2)) title "Hlog" w linespoints ls 1
```

That draws the points twice, which shouldn't be a problem unless you use transparency. I also shrinked the points which are drawn together with the errorbars to 50%, so you don't get problems with antialiasing.

As another option you could add the title only the the errorbars, in which case the legend would look like `|---x---|` (i.e. contain also the errorbars):

```
sc(x) = x*1e-6
plot file1 using ($1/1000):(sc($2)):(sc($3)):(sc($4)) title "Hlog" w yerrorbars ls 1, \
     '' using ($1/1000):(sc($2)) notitle w lines ls 1
```